# I want to install a dual boot windows besides the already installed Ubuntu Studio 19.10, what do I need to do or know prior to that

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-xp, ubuntu-studio

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on mi Toshiba Satellite; and I'd like to install Windows XP SP3 on a separate partition.
I've already separated the disk space for this, when I installed Ubuntu I left a 48gb partition and a 2gb respectively as "do not use", because I was planning to install Windows XP on the small partition and use the other 48 for storage.

Now, I recently searched for this online and it seems that it's not the same as simply putting on the installation bootable USB into the machine and run and it will go as intended (as it would be if I install XP first and then Ubuntu); but the technicalities of it made me simply lost.
I am talking about this post:
[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

I know that Ubuntu uses an EFI partition (or at least that's what I think, I'm really new to Ubuntu, still); my Ubuntu installation has a separate partition for EFI, for Swap, "/" mount, "/boot" mount, boot grub, "/tmp", "/var" and "/home" as well as suggested on this post: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Is there anyone who can please noob it down to me step-by-step on how do I install XP into these unused partitions without screwing up what I already have?

Please have in mind the fact that my laptop does not have a CD tray, it's gotta be installed via USB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t think you will be able to do this. The guide you linked to is not intended for Windows XP. There are many special problems to overcome with XP including the need to provide SATA drivers to the install media. XP will not work at all with a GPT disk which you probably have if it’s a modern laptop. Most advice says XP is incompatible with UEFI which you probably have although some Uber geeks have managed to make that work. However it is very easy to get XP working in something like VirtualBox which might meet your needs. Just choose IDE rather than SATA for the virtual disk

Comment: So, your anwser its a straight "no"?
I don't know how "modern" this laptop is; I bought it second handed and it came with W8.
I think it does have SATA, but I still don't understand what's EFI and what's UEFI, and why just having them makes XP unable to work.
I didn't want to run it in a virtualbox, because I want it to use all the resources the laptop has, not just a few (it doesn't have high specs); that's because I wanna use it for retrogaming some games that just won't play right on WINE, and will play too slow on virtualbox.

Comment: And what I install XP anyway, and then reinstall Ubuntu Studio? What would happen?

Comment: **If** your Ubuntu was installed without UEFI and you're not using GPT, you can install XP onto the partition you've pre-setup, and on next boot your XP should be installed (Ubuntu won't be seen or detected as `grub` will be deactivated with MBR overwritten by XP's install).  This is easily fixed by re-install of `grub` (ie. `grub-install`) from 'live' media.  This assumes you're not GPT partitioned and using MBR and not UEFI. I don't think XP will install on GPT/UEFI anyway and you haven't said how your Ubuntu Studio was installed (indicated it maybe UEFI which thus may require re-install)

Comment: Will this 'grub' be fixed if I run the Boot Repair tool from a USB like https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ ?

Comment: I shut down my XP back in 2011, as it did not have drivers for AHCI which my then new SSD needed. I was able to switch BIOS to boot in IDE to use Windows on MBR drive and AHCI for Ubuntu on SSD. But way too much hassle. UEFI really wants gpt, but XP does not work with it. If you really want XP buy an old used system and install XP on it.

Comment: Yeah, after everyone's advice Imma install W7 instead.
I was gonna install XP because is the windows OS that uses the least amount of resources; but this UEFI is really a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've researched, and as far as I can tell, it's very, but very difficult to run XP from an UEFI laptop, so, the answer is YES, we can, but it's not something I'm gonna pursue because 1)it's too much the hasle, it's not worth it; and 2)I lack the knowledge to run it from an UEFI system.